# Return a view from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have 0 experience in Ajax, and now I'm trying to get an html table to return on an ajax call.

As a result, I get the error

`jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 POST http://test.loc/%7B%7B%20url('blog/articles')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`

I understand that there are still a lot of mistakes, so don't judge too much, and help in any way you can :)

### Route:

`Route::post('blog/articles', 'App\Http\Controllers\BlogController@articles');`

### Ajax on calling page:

```
function getBlogLists(category_id) {
  var category_id = category_id;
  $.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('blog/articles') }}",
      type: 'POST',
      data: { 'category_id': category_id },
      datatype: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
          console.log('success');
          console.log(data);
          
            document.querySelectorAll('.blog-filter__item').forEach(el => {
              el.addEventListener('click', () => {
                document
                  .querySelector('.blog-filter__item.active')
                  .classList.remove('active');
                el.classList.add('active');
            
                  var dataFilter = $(el).attr('data-filter');
            
                  if (dataFilter == 'all') {
                    $('.blog-list').show();
                  }
                  else {
                    $('.blog-list').hide()
                    $(dataFilter).show()
                  }
              });
            });
          
      },
  });
}

//on page load
getBlogLists("{{ $category->id }}");
```

### Controller:

```
public function articles() {
        $input = Request::all();
        if(Request::isMethod('post') && Request::ajax()) {
            if($input['category_id']) {
                $articles = Article::select('select * from blog_categories where blog_category_id = ?', array($input['category_id']));
                $returnHTML = view('blog.articles')->with('articles', $articles)->render();
                return response()->json( array('success', 'html'=>$returnHTML) );
    
            }
        }   
    }
```

### View:

```
@foreach($articles as $index => $article)
    <div class="blog-list category_{{ $article->blog_category_id }}">
        @if ($index % 2 === 1)

        <div class="blog-article blog-article--right">
                <h2 class="blog-article_title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @else

            <div class="blog-article blog-article--left">
                <h2 class="blog-article_title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Change to `datatype: 'json',`

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because you have a problem in your URL.

```
function getBlogLists(category_id) {
  var category_id = category_id;
  $.ajax({
      url: "{{ url('blog/articles') }}",
```

Here, the url is literally `{{ url('blog/articles') }}`, I mean, as a string.

You are sending the request to `http://test.loc/{{ url('blog/articles') }}`, which once encoded gives `http://test.loc/%7B%7B%20url('blog/articles')%20%7D%7D`.

That's why you are getting a 404 error (not found), obviously this url doesn't exist.

First, remove the url variabilization:

```
function getBlogLists(category_id) {
  var category_id = category_id;
  $.ajax({
      url: "http://test.loc/blog/articles", //or whatever your url is
```

Then in your controller, you just have to return the HTML and it will be inside `data` in your javascript `success` callback.

Do a simple test first:

```php
public function articles() {
    return "<h1>HelloWorld</h1>";
}
```

If it works with this simple "hello world", it will work with the view you are rendering as well.

Comment: Changed link - got a new error `jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 POST http://test.loc/blog/articles 419 (unknown status)`

Comment: This is because the csrf token is missing, but I can't say much more since it is off topic regarding your initial error (it's another problem). It is worth another not-so-short full answer. Sending ajax request can be a tedious path!